# How to express "such that" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: word-choice

How to express "such that" at the **beginning** of a  sentence. For example:

I will clean the floor real good. **Such that** you will not see even a stain on it.

In japanese:

地をきれいにするさ。(*Such that*) これぽっちの染色も見えないように

Is there a similar term in japanese? Or does the ように already sort of imply "such that"?

Comment: ように does not imply but explicitly means it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a similar term in japanese?

Yes.
ほどに or くらいに would work.

地をきれいにするさ。これぽっちの染色も見えないくらいに。
地をきれいにするさ。これぽっちの染色も見えないほどに。

---

By the way, if I translate "I will clean the floor real good. Such that you will not see even a stain on it" into Japanese, it's:
床をきれいにするさ。これぽっちのしみも見えないくらいに。
床をきれいにするさ。これぽっちのしみも見えないほどに。

floor → 床
Because 地 stands more for "ground."

stain → しみ
Because 染色 is "coloring something."

Comment: Thanks for the word correction. Appreciate it